# Example needed: How to migrate ingress routing from Nginx to Traefik-V1 (or V2)?

Tags: nginx, traefik, traefik-ingress

I try to switch from nginx to traefik in a Kubernetes cluster. I am totally new to Traefik.

I have an app with Frontend and Backend:

```
demo.myapp.com/ # frontend
demo.myapp.com/backend # backend
```

With `Nginx` I did that following code, which worked like a charm:

```yaml
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: demo-ingress
      namespace: default
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    spec:
      rules:
        - host: demo.myapp.at
          http:
            paths:
              - path: /
                pathType: Prefix
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: frontend-app
                    port:
                      number: 80
              - path: /backend(/|$)(.*)
                pathType: Prefix
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: backend-api
                    port:
                      number: 80
```

Do I need two Ingresses for one domain, if I wanna route to a subfolder?

It seems with `Traefik V1` and `Traefik V2` (where V2 also needs a CRD for `IngressRoute` and/or `Middleware` manifest) more complex.

But I am totally lost with the examples in the docs as well with the mix of Version1 and Version2.

At the moment I use `rancher/library-traefik:1.7.19` but I also can give `V2` a try.

my V1 approach at the moment:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.frontend.rule.type: PathPrefixStrip
spec:
  rules:
    - host: demo.myapp.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              serviceName: frontend-app
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /backend  # old nginx regex -> (/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              serviceName: backend-api
              servicePort: 80
```

Problem with that V1 example:
all paths below `/backend` are not rewritten correctly.
Instead of routing to `/backend/someImage.png` it routes to `/someImage.png`

If someone can help me with an example (optimal would be one for V1 and one for V2), would be great.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

These examples are allegories from the Nginx questioned examples above

For V1

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    # traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-permanent: "true"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-regex: /backend$
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-replacement: /backend/
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/request-modifier: "ReplacePathRegex: ^/backend/(.*) /$1"

spec:
  rules:
    - host: demo.myapp.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              serviceName: frontend-app
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /backend # (/|$)(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              serviceName: backend-api
              servicePort: 80
```

V2

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
  name: demo-ingress-route
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`demo.myapp.com`)
      priority: 0
      services:
        - name: frontend-app
          port: 80
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`demo.myapp.com`) && PathPrefix(`/backend/`)
      middlewares:
        - name: middleware-to-strip-backend-path
      priority: 0
      services:
        - name: backend-api
          port: 80
---
# this middleware will strip /backend from your request to align the requested url to the root / path of your API
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: middleware-to-strip-backend-path
  namespace: default
spec:
  stripPrefix:
    prefixes:
      - /backend
```