# Traefik V2: Why requests to subfolders are not routed properly?

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress

I try to migrate from Traefik `V1` to `V2` **without** the `IngressRoute` or `Middleware`.

my requests to `/backend/something` should be routed to the root of my `backend` service with `/something`.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-regex: /backend$
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-replacement: /backend/
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/request-modifier: "ReplacePathRegex: ^/backend/(.*) /$1"

spec:
  rules:
    - host: demo.myapp.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              serviceName: frontend-app
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /backend # requests to /backend/something should end up in /something
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend-api
                port: http
```

How can I strip that?

At the moment requests to

`/backend/something` ends up in `backend/something/` but should be `/something`

Thank you in advance

PS: is there a "tool" to monitor or test such requests?

This is a demo deployment I work with:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-app
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:latest
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 100Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 100Mi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: http
      restartPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: ClusterIP
  sessionAffinity: None
  sessionAffinityConfig:
    clientIP:
      timeoutSeconds: 10800
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-api
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: hello-world
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-world
          image: rancher/hello-world:latest
          resources: {}
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: http
      restartPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-world
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello-world
  type: ClusterIP
  sessionAffinity: None
  sessionAffinityConfig:
    clientIP:
      timeoutSeconds: 10800
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Comment: What do you mean by: Why requests to subfolders are not routed properly?  Did you get some errors? Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Yes, I get a `404` when calling `/backend/image.jpg`.  And yes, I use bare-metal and it's empty. Only Traefik 2 is deployed. I will add a demo deplyoment.

Comment: Did you try to remove `"` from `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/request-modifier: "ReplacePathRegex: ^/backend/(.*) /$1"` line?

Comment: did you ever got a solution to this? I've spent all day, without luck, trying to solve this

Comment: @Eugene Please let me know if my answer there will solve your porblem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70059632/977017 It has examples for V2 as well V1 with subfolders and a rerouting by removing the prefix

Comment: I've seen that, yes. But those annotations are not present in traefik 2.6 and their documentation... SUCKS. I have not seen a normal guide on how to migrate without middleware. If rancher would have not used traefik by default, I would have never used it.

Comment: @Eugene I kicked Rancher... I am doing everything with Lens App. https://k8slens.dev/ Try the answer I've added. This is what I am using currently. it works (in my case)

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: production-ingress
  namespace: production
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: web, websecure
    # usage: namespace-middlewareName@kubernetescrdIsMandatory
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: production-middleware-frontend@kubernetescrd,production-middleware-backend@kubernetescrd
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: "true"
    # cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
  rules:
    - host: yourdomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend
                port:
                  number: 5000
          - path: /backend
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend
                port:
                  number: 3000
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "yourdomain.com"
      secretName: yourdomain-com-production-tls
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: middleware-backend
  namespace: production
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  stripPrefix:
    prefixes:
      - /backend
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: middleware-frontend
  namespace: production
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  stripPrefix:
    prefixes:
      - /
```